# Reached MAX size for compiled-sql statement cache for database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

My code is

```
ContentValues values; 
values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SQLHelper.EMPLOYEE_LPN, jsObj.getString("lpn"));
db.update(SQLHelper.EMPLOYEE_TABLE, values,
                "EMPLOYEE_LPN ='" + jsObj.getString("lpn") + "'",
                null);
```

a warning is shown in the Log Cat

```
08-31 15:19:45.297: WARN/Database(2868): Reached MAX size for compiled-sql statement cache for database /data/data/org.sipdroid.sipua/databases/test.db; i.e., 
NO space for this sql statement in cache: 
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME FROM eyemployee WHERE EMPLOYEE_LPN ='1169162'. 
Please change your sql statements to use '?' for bindargs, instead of using actual values
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: do as logger is telling you...Please change your sql statements to use '?' for bindargs instead of using actual values

Comment: @ Rahul i gave db.update(SQLHelper.EMPLOYEE_TABLE, values, SQLHelper.EMPLOYEE_LPN + "=?",  new String[]{jsObj.getString("lpn")}); bt still the warning is shown in the log cat

Comment: why are you trying to update EMPLOYEE_LPN to X and in your where clause also you are specifying EMPLOYEE_LPN=X..its is like 'update table set x=1 where x=1'

Comment: @ Rahul  could u pls explain with sample code pls...i didn't get u

Comment: you want to update SQLHelper.EMPLOYEE_LPN to jsObj.getString("lpn")....then there is no point in putting SQLHelper.EMPLOYEE_LPN = jsObj.getString("lpn") in where clause..there is no use of this query..e.g. your query looks like "update users set name='jennifer' where name='jennifer'"

Comment: Why doesn't the cache clear itself ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at examples 8-3 and 8-4 [here](http://androidapps.org.ua/i_sect11_d1e7013.html).

**Example 8-3. Using the update method**

```
/**
 * Update a job in the database.
 * @param job_id         The job id of the existing job
 * @param employer_id    The employer offering the job
 * @param title          The job title
 * @param description    The job description
 */
public void editJob(long job_id, long employer_id, String title, String description) {
    ContentValues map = new ContentValues();
    map.put("employer_id", employer_id);
    map.put("title", title);
    map.put("description", description);
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(job_id)};
    try{
        getWritableDatabase().update("jobs", map, "_id=?", whereArgs);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("Error writing new job", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Here are some of the highlights of the code in Example 8-3:

Example 8-4 shows you how to use the execSQL method.
**Example 8-4. Using the execSQL method**

```
/**
 * Update a job in the database.
 * @param job_id         The job id of the existing job
 * @param employer_id    The employer offering the job
 * @param title          The job title
 * @param description    The job description
 */
public void editJob(long job_id, long employer_id, String title, String description) {
    String sql = 
        "UPDATE jobs " +
        "SET employer_id = ?, "+
        " title = ?,  "+
        " description = ? "+
        "WHERE _id = ? ";
    Object[] bindArgs = new Object[]{employer_id, title, description, job_id};
    try{
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql, bindArgs);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("Error writing new job", e.toString());
    }
}
```

---

The message is asking you to make parameters use sql variables instead of sql literals.

Each sql query is parsed, plans are generated, and stored in a sql statement cache.

Queries which have the same text are fetched from the cache.

```
  --One query
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = @1   (@1 = 3)
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = @1   (@1 = 4)
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = @1   (@1 = 5)
```

Queries which have different text (including literals) cannot be found in the cache and are (uselessly) added to it.

```
  --Three Queries.
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = 3
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = 4
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id = 5
```

Comment: Are you sure 8-4 is a valid choice?  The latest API docs for the bindArgs version of execSQL says "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE." http://bit.ly/1gGhsUV

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this today, and came across this doc.

http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder

This solved my issue. This is the code from the link above

```
QueryBuilder<Account, String> queryBuilder =
  accountDao.queryBuilder();
Where<Account, String> where = queryBuilder.where();
SelectArg selectArg = new SelectArg();
// define our query as 'name = ?'
where.eq(Account.NAME_FIELD_NAME, selectArg);
// prepare it so it is ready for later query or iterator calls
PreparedQuery<Account> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();

// later we can set the select argument and issue the query
selectArg.setValue("foo");
List<Account> accounts = accountDao.query(preparedQuery);
// then we can set the select argument to another
// value and re-run the query
selectArg.setValue("bar");
accounts = accountDao.query(preparedQuery);
```