# How do I fix the syntax error on an INSERT INTO command?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-insert

Inside an `onClick()` event, I am trying to increment a counter value by 1 in my CARDNUM column within a SQLite database table (TOTALCOUNT) using the INSERT INTO command.

The error occurs when trying to run:

```
 db.execSQL(INCREMENT_COUNT2);
```

Android Studio gives the following error message

```
"SQLiteException: near "cardnum": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO totalcount(cardnum) VALUES cardnum+1"
```

What am I missing here?
Is there a better way to achieve the increment upon INSERTion?

DatabaseHelper.java file:

```
// Increment the counter in the TOTALCOUNT Table in the database.
public void insertIntoTableTOTALCOUNT() {

    // Get a reference to a writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();

    db.execSQL(INCREMENT_COUNT1);
    db.execSQL(INCREMENT_COUNT2);

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    if(db.isOpen())
        db.close();
    }

// Set the counter to a default value of zero.
public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT1 = " INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT +
    "(" + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+")" + " VALUES (0)";

// Increment the Cardnum count by +1 for each onClick.
public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT2 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES " + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +"+1";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct SQL command:

```
public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT2 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM + ") VALUES (" + (COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM + 1) + ")";
```

But using bound parameters would be a better choice.

Comment: I will try that.  I haven't ever used bound parameters.  Is that to minimize SQL injection?  Can you point to any good links that will help educate me on the advantages of using them?

Comment: Yes, but not only. It also voids you the need to enclose strings in quotes or to double apostrophes. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857073/queries-with-prepared-statements-in-android

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you want to UPDATE the value of COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM with +1 and not INSERT a new row. If that is correct, you statement should be

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT SET COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM=COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+1 WHERE <filter criteria>
```

If you indeed want to INSERT a new row with COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+1, then you have to fetch the MAX of COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM from DB and then increment it and insert

```
SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM) FROM TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT
```

Then increment it by 1 and insert.

Comment: I am looking to insert a new row with the +1.  So I want to take the value of the last previously inserted row and add one.  So do you recommend I use your SELECT MAX example?

Comment: Yes correct. I don't the exact logic of COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM, but if it is supposed to the +1 than the last inserted row (and thus unique), then you should select MAX first and then increment that value and then insert.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try.

Comment: Also, if CARDNUM is supposed to be unique, you can consider making it a  PK with auto-increment - CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT(
   COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT);

Answer (score 1):

Make a Method pass the Cardnum value by adding or incrementing 1. Then run the insert Query. There are two types of SQL query for Insertion.

1. Raw Query i.e String insertdata= "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES " + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +"+1";
2. Another is by using ContentValues:

   `public void insertDatatoDatabase(String data1,String data2){
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(COLUMN1, data1); 
           values.put(COLUMN2, data2);db1.insert(TABLE_DETAIL, null, values);
   }`

You are adding +1 in String " " where it is a Integer. Try adding them in bracket or Add the number before inserting and send it from onclick only.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static final String INCREMENT_COUNT2 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES (" + (COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM=COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+1)+")";
```

//use this may be it will be worked

Comment: Error message: "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM'.

Comment: "Cannot assign a value to final variable 'COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM'.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
INCREMENT_COUNT2 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME_TOTALCOUNT + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM+") VALUES (" + COLUMN_NAME_CARDNUM +"+1)"
```

Comment: app crashes with error message: "no such column: cardnum (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO totalcount(cardnum) VALUES (cardnum+1)"